# Modify React Child Component props after render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, clipboard.js

Here's a simple example:

```
copyButton = <SomeReactComponent title="My Button" />

this.clipboard = new Clipboard('button#copy-button');
this.clipboard.on('success', () => { 
    this.copyButton.props.title = "Copied!";
});

render = () => {
    return (
        ...
        { this.copyButton }
        ...
    );
}
```

Using [Clipboard.js](https://clipboardjs.com/), when my button is pressed, I copy some text to the clipboard. On a successful copy, I want to change the title of my copy button to reflect that. The button component, which I keep a reference to, has already been rendered and `this.copyButton.props.title` obviously doesn't work because components are immutable.

How then, would I go about changing the value of `title` on my button? I know I could have a state property in the parent component but I'd rather avoid that to keep my parent component complete stateless. Could I simply reassign `this.copyButton` inside the success callback (I tried that but no luck)?

Speaking more generally, how should parent components update their children's props if at all? Is using state really the only way?

Note: I'm using ES6 if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you're trying to update the state of the button's text, not using react state in some form (in the parent or child component) will probably feel a bit hacky.  However, it is possible.  The initial method that comes to mind is to use `React.cloneElement` to create a new version of `copyButton` with the `title` prop that you want. Then use `this.forceUpdate` to rerender the parent component with the update child component.  Something like this:

```
this.clipboard.on('success', () => { 
    this.copyButton = React.cloneElement(this.copyButton, {
        title: 'Copied!'
    });
    this.forceUpdate();
});
```

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.cloneelement

That being said, using `state` in this case would almost certainly be better both for readability and runtime (cloning elements and forcing a re-render isn't cheap).

Comment: Yeah I went with just using state in the parent component. Also -_-

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't feel very Reacty to me.

I think you want to be doing something like this:

```
getInitialState = () => {
  return {
    title: 'Button Title'
  };
};

componentDidMount = () => {
  this.clipboard = new Clipboard(this.refs.copyButton);
  this.clipboard.on('success', () => { 
    this.setState({
      title: 'Copied!'
    })
  });
};

componentWillUnmount = () => {
  // You should destroy your clipboard and remove the listener
  // when the component unmounts to prevent memory leaks
  this.clipboard.destroy();
  // or whatever the comparable method is for clipboard.js
};

render = () => {
  return (
    ...
    <SomeReactComponent ref="copyButton" title={this.state.title} />
    ...
  );
};
```

The end result is that your button mounts on initial render. Then its [ref](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html) is passed into `componentDidMount()` which instantiates your clipboard and `success` listener. When your button is clicked, it calls `this.setState()` to update the button component's internal `title` state, which automatically triggers a re-render of your component with the new title.

Also, according to the [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#forceupdate), you want to try to avoid using `forceUpdate()` if you can.

> Normally you should try to avoid all uses of forceUpdate() and only read from this.props and this.state in render(). This makes your component "pure" and your application much simpler and more efficient.